# Drawing line in TikZ with newcommand

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create a command to draw a line between two points. The command needs to take line styles as an argument. The following MWE works as expected:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\testtikz}[1]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[#1] (0,0) -- (1,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \testtikz{red,line width=1mm}
\end{document}
```

For my use case I need the parameter to be `def`'d and passed to the command, as in:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\testtikz}[1]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[#1] (0,0) -- (1,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \def\tikzparams{red,line width=1mm}
    \testtikz{\tikzparams}
\end{document}
```

This results in an error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/red,line width=1mm' and I
 am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

This seems to crop up as long as there is a comma or an equal sign in `\tikzparams`. How can I work around this?

Comment: Use a style instead of a `newcommand`. `\tikzset{myparams/.style={red,line width=1mm}}` and `\testtikz{myparams}`.

Comment: And by the way, it's probably better to use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`, that way you're sure you're not overwriting some existing macro.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately this part of a much larger project. Placing `\tikzset` inside the `\newcommand` yields the same problems, and I can't reliably assume that `\tikzset` will be called where I need it.

Comment: (I don't quite understand, so the rest of this comment might just make you frustrated at me.) Your `\def` is *outside* the `\newcommand`, why can't you just replace the `\def` with a `\tikzset`? If you can assume that the `\def` is in the right place, why can't you assume the `\tikzset` is in the right place?

Comment: Sorry, I phrased that very poorly.

The larger system takes a series of [style][coordinate] pairs and waits for a `\plotthemall` command; based on the coordinates passed it will work in whatever necessary way. You are right that I could `\tikzset` as many styles as necessary, then call them with [definedstyle1][coordinate], [definedstyle2][coordinate], etc., but IMO it is way more usable/readable to inline the styles as [red,dashed][coordinate], [blue,dotted][coordinate], etc.

Comment: Ultimately my problem is that I have a conflict between `media9` and `egameps`. There are ways around this but I also find some aspects `egameps` really annoying, so I'm reworking similar functionality in TikZ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand the argument before passing it to `\draw`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\testtikz}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[#1] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\def\tikzparams{red,line width=1mm}

\testtikz{\tikzparams}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this double `\expandafter` works? I had tried single and double `\expandafter`s (before `\draw`), but obviously they didn't work. My understanding of `\expandafter` is hazy (like many people's).

Comment: @kyle: `\expandafter\X\Y` first expands `\Y` before calling `\X`. We need to jump over `\draw` as well as the token `[` which starts the optional argument, so we use two `\expandafter`s. So, with `\def\Y{abc}`, `\expandafter\X\expandafter[\Y]` turns into `\X[abc]`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I did not realize that `[` was a token.